# Ordenar decreciente alfabeticamente una cola dinamica en JAVA

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, queue

Tengo que ordenar los valores ingresados en una cola dinámica en forma decreciente alfabéticamente en la cola, y para esto he creado el método `OrdenaDecreciente`, para que los ordene directamente al mostrar los valores.

Pensé en ejecutar el método [quicksort](/questions/tagged/quicksort), pero no sé cómo interpretarlo en el código.

En resumen, quiero definir el método de salida de ordenar los valores de forma decreciente alfabéticamente en el método llamado `OrdenDecreciente`, en el archivo de definiciones y luego poder ejecutarlo en el código de prueba.

Dejo el código de las definiciones de las variables, y el código de ejecución aquí debajo.
Este es el código de las definiciones

```
public class CuaDina {
    class Nodo {
        String info;
        Nodo sig;
    }
        
    private Nodo p,u;
    
    public CuaDina () {
        p = null;
        u = null;
    }
    
    public void buidar() {
        p = null;
        u = null;
    }
    
    public boolean isbuida() {
        return (p == null);
    }
    
    public void insertar(String x) {
        Nodo nuevo;
        nuevo = new Nodo();
        nuevo.info = x;
        nuevo.sig = null;
        if (p == null) p = nuevo;
        else u.sig = nuevo;
        u = nuevo;
    }
    
    public String extraer ()
    {
        String informacion = p.info;
        p = p.sig;
        if (p == null) u = null; // És opcional ja que mai es controla sol
        return informacion;
    }
    
    public String imprimir() {
        String mostrar = "";
        Nodo reco = p;
        while (reco != null) {
            mostrar = mostrar + reco.info +" - ";
            reco=reco.sig;
        }
        return mostrar;
    }
    public String OrdenaDecreciente() {

    }

}
```

Este es el código de ejecución.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class UsaCuaDina {
        public static CuaDina Cua;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        Cua = new CuaDina();
        int Opcion;
        do
        {
            Opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "1. INTRODUIR DADES\n"+
                    "2. ELIMINAR DADES\n"+
                    "3. VEURE DADES\n"+
                    "4. BUIDAR CUA\n"+
                    "5. ORDENAR DECRECIENTE CUA\n"+       
                    "6. SALIR\n"+
                    "--------------------------------------------------------\n"+
                    "DONA'M LA TEVA OPCION [1 - 6]","MENU CUA",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
             
            switch(Opcion)
            {
                case 1: inserta(Cua);break;
                case 2: extrae(Cua);break;
                case 3: imprime(Cua);break;
                case 4: buida(Cua);break;
                case 5: OrdenaDecreciente(Cua);break;
                case 6: break; //System.exit(0); break;
                default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"OPCIÃ“ NO VALIDA \n","ERROR OPCIÃ“",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);break;
            }
        }
        while(Opcion != 6); 
    }
    
    public static void inserta (CuaDina P)
    {
        String valor;
        valor = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"DONA'M EL VALOR A INTRODUIR"));            
        P.insertar(valor);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"EL VALOR " + valor + " S'HA INTRODUIT A LA CUA");
    }        

    public static void extrae (CuaDina P)
    {
        if(P.isbuida()) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"LA CUA ESTÃ€ BUIDA");
        else            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hem extret de la pila el valor: "+P.extraer(),"EXTRACCIÃ“",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    }        

    public static void buida (CuaDina P)
    {
        P.buidar();
    }        

    public static void imprime(CuaDina P) {
        if(P.isbuida())
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"LA CUA ESTÃ€ BUIDA\n NO HI HAN DADES A MOSTRAR","MOSTRAR DADES",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        else
            {
                String mostrar = P.imprimir();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"LES DADES DE LA CUA SÃ“N : \n"+mostrar,"LLISTAT DE LA CUA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
       public static void OrdenaDecreciente(CuaDina P) {
        if(P.isbuida())
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"LA CUA ESTÃ€ BUIDA\n NO HI HAN DADES A MOSTRAR","MOSTRAR DADES",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        else
            {
                String resultado2 = P.imprimir();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"LES DADES DE LA CUA DE FORMA DECRECIENTE : \n"+resultado2,"LLISTAT DE LA CUA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Una cola es un [TDA](https://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~bebustos/apuntes/cc30a/TDA/#:~:text=Un%20Tipo%20de%20dato%20abstracto,como%20est%C3%A9n%20implementadas%20dichas%20operaciones.) y  tiene las siguientes operaciones: Encolar, desencolar y frente. No puedes ordenar de forma decreciente una cola, porque estarías alterando el orden de los elementos. Ten en cuenta que la cola usa el método FIFO (el primero en entrar, es el primero en salir) y si ordenas la cola, pierde el sentido de la *cola*.

Comment: Lo que si podrías ordenar por ejemplo es un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) a través del método [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

Answer (score 0):

si usas un ArrayList podrias hacerlo utilizando:

```
 //ordena la lista alfabeticamente de a 'a' hasta la 'z'
   Collections.sort(lista);
   //invierte el orden de la lista quedando en sentido de 'z' hasta 'a'
   Collections.reverse(lista);
```

Aqui un codigo de ejemplo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class practice {

    public ArrayList<String> sortearItems(ArrayList<String> lista) {
        Collections.sort(lista);
        Collections.reverse(lista);
        return lista;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        lista.add("a");
        lista.add("d");
        lista.add("b");
        lista.add("c");
        System.out.println("lista sin ordenar" + lista);
        Collections.sort(lista);
        System.out.println("lista ordenada alfabeticamente" + lista);
        Collections.reverse(lista);
        System.out.println("Lista con orden revertido" + lista);
    }
}
```

Comment: La respuesta está bien, pero faltó mencionar por qué no es posible ordenar directamente su estructura para propornerle usar un `ArrayList` en su lugar. Quizás podrías haber dicho que si su clase `CuaDina` implementa la interfaz `List`, podrá usar la función `Collections.sort` con ella.